# How to set highlight color for Radar Chart in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Is there any way to change the highlight color for Radar Chart using MPAndroidChart library?

[image: MPAndroidChart - Radar Chart highlight line]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, it is a little bit tricky, at least for me :-).

The highlight color is set using RadarDataSet object, which is essential to build the Radar Chart in MPAndroidChart lib.

so i.e. red highlight line is achieved with:

```
radarDataSet.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
```